# How do I suppress ICE errors from merge modules

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I build an installer using WiX 3.5. The installer utilizes VB6 merge modules. I always get a lot of error messages from light similar to this:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE03: Table: Class Column: CLSID Missing specifications in _Validation Table (or Old Database)
```

So, VB6 is obviously old and I should assume it's an Old Database. That's why I want to ignore the error messsage since I must be careful with the errors from my WiX source.

When I pass `-sw03` to candle and light the error messages are NOT suppressed. I also don't want suppress errors caused by other modules. How do I get rid off the problems with the old merge modules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ICEs run against the final .msi package; once merge modules are linked in, the ICE code has no way of knowing which rows in which tables came from which merge modules. You can file a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=105970&atid=642717) for WiX to support running validation before merge modules are linked in, but that wouldn't let you validate other merge modules. No good solution, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 20):

I too had same problem but then found pretty simple solution. Just suppress the ICE validations from the WIX project as shown below
Go to tools settings property and check "Suppress ICE Validations" box
[image]

Comment: I want to suppress the other module's warnings because I want to see my errors. Your suggestion also hides also errors in my wxs source.