# ICE61: This product should remove only older versions of itself. The Maximum version is not less than the current product

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am getting the following warning in Visual Studio:

> ICE61: This product should remove only older versions of itself. The Maximum version is not less than the current product.

I have found [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249783/613605), but I can't apply what it says, my code only has this:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Product Name" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.2" Manufacturer="Ace Software" UpgradeCode="d2562e98-94df-8938-ba21-0967b39ed389">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure='yes' />

    <Upgrade Id="d2562e98-94df-8938-ba21-0967b39ed389">
      <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0.0"
                      IncludeMinimum="yes"
                      Maximum="100.100.100.100"
                      Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" />
    </Upgrade>

    <!-- other code ommited -->
</Product>
```

As you can see, I don't have a `MajorUpgrade` element where I can set the `AllowSameVersionUpgrades` to `no`.

How do I get rid of the warning? I don't really want to supress it, but actually fix the issue.

Comment: MSI can recognize only 3 first digits of version, 4th digit is omitted, version `1.0.0.2` and `1.0.0.3` are recognized as the same. Also it's recommended to use `MajorUpgrade` element to allow upgrade. Look at the wix [documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html)

Comment: Thank you @PavelAnikhouski can you reply as answer please? So I can mark the question as answered. Your advice about using `MajorUpgrade` instead was awesome. It was much simpler and it worked. I also went down to `1.0.0` (3 number sections instead of 4).

Comment: [Just a link you can check for more help resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809294/winows-installer-wix-install-product-twice/57809491#57809491).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI can recognize only 3 first digits of version, 4th digit is omitted, version `1.0.0.2` and `1.0.0.3` are recognized as the same. Also it's recommended to use `MajorUpgrade` element to allow upgrade. Have a look at the [major upgrade](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html) documentation