# New version info resources result in "error LGHT1076: ICE03: String overflow ...Column: Language, Key(s):

Tags: winapi, wix

I have added a couple of new localized versioninfo resources to a .exe file I distribute with one of my installers and all of a sudden, light complains about the following for each language added:

error LGHT1076: ICE03: String overflow (greater than length permitted in column); Table: File, Column: Language, Key(s): xxxxxx

I have to admit that I am using WiX version 3.6 which is clearly outdated. Can I safely ignore this problem? Is this a problem in my version of WiX? Do I have to worry about this?

TIA,

-- 
Stefan Kuhr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it a common warning that is part of the [ICE03](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368798(v=vs.85).aspx) validation process.

You can [suppress Specific ICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055476/how-do-i-suppress-ice-errors-from-merge-modules) in you Project properties.

Comment: Thanks Arkady. I know how to suppress that warning from within votive. Is there a way to suppress it only for the relevant files, like in Visual C with #pragma warning (push/pop) so I do not overlook it at other places where it might be thrown for a real purpose? And is it really safe to be ignored in this place (my scenario with the localized resources), does it do any harm?  Thanks again!

Comment: It does not do any harm, you can suppress only by configuration, and even if there is a msbuild manipulation to do this by file it is not worth the time and effort.

Comment: Thanks. In retrospect I see that part of my questions was stupid: The ICE validation runs as part of the LIGHT linking process, not the compile process where something like temporarily disabling specific ICE would make sense. Are there any cases where this warning should alert me, what is this warning for at all?

Comment: Look at the warnings as in cs warning. Like "The variable 'MyException' is declared but never used".